# ggplot2 fails to draw curved line

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, line

I am trying to draw a curved line in ggplot2 which should look like this:

[image]
However, in ggplot2 I can only draw in the line in the following way:

[image]

Here is the code that I have used to create both pictures:

```
 df1 <- data.frame(dollar = c(0,5,10,20,30), value = c(0,200,300, -100, -300))
 # draw line graph with base plot
 plot(y = df1$dollar, x = df1$emiss_red, type = "l")
 # draw line graph with ggplot
 ggplot() + geom_line(data = df1, aes(y = dollar, x = value), size =1)
```

Ggplot2 seems to order the data frame according to x value and then connect the points according to the x-value. However, I do not want my graph to be ordered.

Additionally, I do not want to flip the axis around, since dollar value must appear on the y-axis. Since I prefer to create these graphs in ggplot2, does anyone know how to accomplish this?

Comment: Change `geom_line` to `geom_path`!

Comment: @JLLagrange Could at least one of you write an official answer for this, so that it can be accepted? Don't pass up easy rep! ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to swap `geom_line` to `geom_path`.  As noted in [the documentation](http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3.1/geom_path.html), `geom_path` connects "observations in original order", while [geom_line](http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3.1/geom_line.html) connects "observations, ordered by x value".

So the last line would be

```
ggplot() + geom_path(data = df1, aes(y = dollar, x = value), size =1)
```